# How to separate Class Library into multiple assembly (*.dll)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-core

I build a class library project with separate class by folder.

Example:

- TEST

  - Security
  - Converter
  - Utility

After I compile project, I will have **TEST.dll**

but I want TEST.dll, TEST.Security.dll, TEST.Converter.dll, & TEST.Utility.dll

**Note:**  Security, Converter, Utility is folder in TEST project. In each folder have c# class.

## How to do?

Comment: create separate projects for each

Comment: right click solution, create new project, you are on your way.

Comment: Also what have you tried, whats not working for you, what did you research?

Comment: how about namespace?

Comment: OK let's me try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create separate projects for each

Example:

- name project **TEST.Security** class library
- name project  **TEST.Converter** class library
- name project  **TEST.Utility** class library

Answer (score 2):

the fact that you separate classes by folders means nothing when it comes to the dll output.

If you want one dll per folder then you will have to create one separate class library project for each one. In the properties of each project you can set the name of the dll file itself.

This being said, the name of the dll is less important, it's the namespaces that will matter. The namespace is set in each class file and this will affect your "using" statements.